# real time visualization of heart rate data on a graph

Tags: training, heart-rate-monitor, app

I want an app that will visualize my heart rate on a graph real-time while I do exercise.

The heart rate information will be coming from a smart bluetooth (4.0) sensor.   Preferably, the software would be running on either android, or some windows OS.   I'd relegate myself to using IOS only if there were no options for the other OSs.

Endomondo and Strava don't appear to have integrated this feature into their apps, but I can't imagine that plotting some points on a graph is beyond their skill.

Can someone identify for me an app that will do this?

Thanks

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an application recommendation that isn't fitness related.

Comment: I'm asking about the visualization of heart rate data.  Heart rate data is inherently fitness related.  
Evidence: Every cyclist, runner, swimmer, and fitness enthusiast that I know has at least 2 HRMs.   

Fitness, when abstracted from the tools that we use to measure it, does not serve a purpose.  The fact that the request domain intersects with a software recommendation should not exclude it from this stack exchange.

Comment: HOW is it fitness related? How would knowing/seeing this information help your own fitness program? Your basic questions is "I need an app to do X". Just because X relates to a body part doesn't make it fitness oriented. Same if I asked "I want to plot my O2 sats on a graph. What app will do that?" Simply saying "While I do exercise" doesn't make it on topic.

Comment: You know, there isn't an app that can do this afaik but I stumbled across this question when doing some market research as I'm considering to *build* one like this. Do you want to message me? My contact is in my profile. Thanks!

Comment: I've found that this feature already exists in the workout feature of Golden Cheetah.   Thanks for everyone who expressed interest.